# Restarting firefox using the developer console (shift+F2) makes every restarted window have the developer console open

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

When I restart firefox using the developer console, i press shift+F2 and then I write

> restart

in the command line that comes up at the bottom and press ENTER.

This is of course a very useful feature, every window dissapears and comes back, but each restarted window will also have the developer console opened as if I was pressing shift+F2 on everyone of them.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Developer Toolbar is a global thing, just like any other toolbar (e.g. Nav Bar or Bookmarks Bar). Firefox will remember the visiblity state and will restore it when opening new windows, either the usual way, or after a restart.

Comment: Is there a way to restart firefox without having a lot of windows with a developer toolbar open afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Just close the toolbar in one window, and it will be closed in every other window as well.